# Why the same logic reaches 10 $digest() iterations in filter but not in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I've created a filter to extract a grouped simple array from a complex array of objects:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | myFilter"></li>
```

and I face this error:

> Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

I move the same logic without any changes to controller:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in myFilterFunction(items)"></li>
```

and it's working properly.
The question is what's the difference between running the same code within a filter or a function in controller?

**Note:** This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alihaghighatkhah/xfewbxmv/1/) illustrating the problem, if you use filter you'll see the error in console, and if you use the function in controller instead of filter, the error is gone and it works properly

Comment: Would you mind to show your implementation of the function?

Comment: @Eddi I've added a fiddle.

Comment: because filter does pipe it to `ng-repeat`, so if your filter is updated items array on $scope, then it will go in infinite loop

Comment: @entre but I'm not changing anything in `$scope`, I'm returning a new array. I'm I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your filter doesn't actually filter the input. It transforms it and creates completely new objects every time it's called. So every time a new digest cycle starts, and in every digest cycle ngRepeat calls the filter again. You simply cannot use a filter that way.

Comment: What you mentioned is the common case causing this problem, the difference is that, as you see in the fiddle, I'm using a local array variable inside the filter, and I'm assigning some of the **Primary typed** values of the model object, then I'm returning the same local array variable. So I'm not making any changing in the model. Or at least I think so.

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah What do you think `item` is? It's part of the model and it's derived from `items | myFilter`, not `items`. You return a different array with different values in each digest cycle. It may look the same, but it **is** not the same, because arrays and objects are reference types. So, yes, you **are** actually changing the model.